# Why some search engines show address with www and some not, and how to tell which one needs to be shown

Tags: heroku, search-engines

In some SEs our site is shown with www and in some without. In Heroku both domains are specified and lead to the same page, but we want to crearify address to be without www and trainling slashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include a [canonical link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) in your page content:

> A **canonical link element** is an HTML element that helps webmasters prevent duplicate content issues in search engine optimization by specifying the "canonical" or "preferred" version of a web page.

Including something like this in your `<head>` tag

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/some/page">
```

tells search engines (and other entities) that the given URL, without a `www` subdomain and without trailing slashes, is preferred. Include this on all pages, e.g. via a shared template.

Alternatively, you could redirect all requests to the `www` subdomain to your preferred domain and similarly redirect requests with a trailing slash to the version without. If you use a permanent redirect ([HTTP code 301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_redirection)), search engines should figure out that you want to use those URLs. But this will also affect end users, redirecting their browsers.

No matter what approach you take, it will take some time for search engines to reindex your site and start showing your preferred URLs. Some search providers let you [request a reindex](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/ask-google-to-recrawl), which can speed things up a bit.